# Understanding and Reading jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have an html file that loads up file.js and it looks something like this

```
(($) => { *some code* })(jQuery);
```

I really don't understand what (($) => indicates. And what the (jQuery) at the end does. Is this a special notation? I understand javascript jQuery calls written more like this:

```
<script>$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#getMessage").on("click", function(){

    });
});</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called currying, so basically

```
(($) => { *some code* })
```

creates a function which needs `$`.

And then you apply it with `jQuery`.

A simple example would be,

```
((x) => console.log(x))(100);
// will print 100
```

You can more about it here, https://www.sitepoint.com/currying-in-functional-javascript/.

Answer (score 0):

This whole `(($) => { *some code* })(jQuery);` is an Immediately Invoking function expression(IIFE). An IIFE generally looks like this

```
(function(){
// rest of code
}())
```

`=>` is an [**Arrow functions**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) which is  anew way of writing function introduced in ES6.

`(jquery)` is passing the global jquery instead of creating a new instance of it.
So it boils down to creating a new arrow function expression which require   jquery